# Logger.info() always giving me undefined

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have a logger.ts file like this. But When I'm checking logs, I always get undefined. Even if I print logger.info('Hello, world!'). What could be the reason for this?

```
import winston from 'winston'
import path from 'path'
import DailyRotateFile from 'winston-daily-rotate-file'
const loggerInstances = new Map<string, winston.Logger>()

export const LoggerFactory: (label: string) => winston.Logger = (
  label: string
) => {
  let logger = loggerInstances.get(label)
  if (logger != null) {
    return logger
  }

  // if no logger with that label exists yet
  // create, cache and return new logger
  logger = getLogger(label)
  loggerInstances.set(label, logger)
  return logger
}

const transport = new DailyRotateFile({
  filename: './logs/app-%DATE%.log', // use a relative path instead of an absolute path
  datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  zippedArchive: true,
  maxFiles: '15d',
  handleExceptions: true,
})

function getLogger(label: string): winston.Logger {
  return winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    exitOnError: false,
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.timestamp(),
      winston.format.label({ label: label }),
      winston.format.splat()
      // winston.format.json()
    ),
    transports: [
      transport,
      new winston.transports.Console()
    ],
  })
}
```

When I'm calling it inside route, I'm always getting undefined. I have imported the logger file like this

```
import { LoggerFactory } from '../../libs/logger'
const logger = LoggerFactory('test.ts')
```

```
router.get('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
console.log("logger", logger)

  try {
    logger.info('Hello, world!');
    res.send('Hello, world!');
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`An error occurred: ${err}`);
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
});
```

When I console.log logger, I get the following output

```
ogger <ref *1> DerivedLogger {
[1]   _readableState: ReadableState {
[1]     flowing: true,
[1]     ended: false,
[1]     endEmitted: false,
[1]     reading: true,
[1]     sync: false,
[1]     needReadable: true,
[1]     emittedReadable: false,
[1]     readableListening: false,
[1]     resumeScheduled: false,
[1]     paused: false,
[1]     emitClose: true,
[1]     autoDestroy: false,
[1]     destroyed: false,
[1]     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
.............
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a new logger instance directly using the getLogger function instead of the LoggerFactory. Like the following. Let me know if this works?

```
import { getLogger } from '../../libs/logger'
const logger = getLogger('test.ts')
```